# Como imprimir en un jtext como si fuese consola?

Tags: java

Me refiero a:

```
for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    sout(r+","); //jtext.setText(r + ",")
```

> 0,1,2,3,4,

ya que en el jtext imprimiría solo lo ultimo 4,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

1. Defines un *String* en donde almacenarás el texto
2. Usas tu ciclo para ir concatenando los números
3. Por último colocas la cadena resultante en tu JTextField (imagino es lo que usas)

Así quedaría:

```
String cad = "";
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    cad += i + ", ";
jtext.setText(cad); // cad = "1, 2, 3, 4, "
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.